# dataframe merger column operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

I want to 'merge' the three columns to form a D column, the rule is: if there is at least one '1' in the row, then the value of D is '1' else is '0'. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for compare values with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row and last cast boolean mask to `integer`s:

```
df['D'] = df.eq(1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  0
2  3  3  3  0
3  4  1  1  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.eq(1))
       A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False   True   True

print (df.eq(1).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```